# See if regex returns no matches in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

```
matchData = Regexp.new(/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\D\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\D/)


puts matchData.match("2015-08-21T13:54:29Z")

if ( !matchData  || (matchData.size==0) )
 puts "here"
end
```

I have a date format that I'm trying to check to see if it returns nil or not. Right now it is matching what I want it to match, however when it doesn't match (a date format) then I can't seem to find what it is returning. It is just blank, but it isn't nil. Is there some method I can use to check the length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to check for a match, you can do it like this:

```
if "string" =~ /regex/
  # do something
end
```

About why your example is not working: what you called `matchData` is the regex, and you never saved a reference to the actual `MatchData`. What you wanted to say was:

```
regex = Regexp.new(/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\D\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\D/)
matchData = regex.match("2015-08-21T13:54:29Z")

puts "here" unless matchData
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be using [DateTime::strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime) (instead of a regex):

```
require 'date'

dt = DateTime.strptime('2015-08-21T13:54:29Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
  #=> #<DateTime: 2015-08-21T13:54:29+00:00 ((2457256j,50069s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Not only does this tell you whether the string contains a date and time in the specified format (if it does not, `strptime` raises an `ArgumentError: invalid date` exception that you'd `rescue`), but if it does the parsing of date and time elements is done for you:

```
d = dt.to_date
  #=> #<Date: 2015-08-21 ((2457256j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> 
d.year  #=> 2015 
d.month #=> 8 
d.day   #=> 21 
d.wday  #=> 5 

t = dt.to_time
  #=> 2015-08-21 06:54:29 -0700 
t.hour  #=> 6 
t.min   #=> 54 
t.sec   #=> 29
```